# What is reasonable size of outgoing and incoming emails configured in mail server?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I'm wondering what is reasonable size of outgoing/incoming mail configured in mail server (in my case postfix). What is the risk of setting this size to big. Does it depends only on parameters of my server ?

Comment: What are yor incoming and outgoing email size requirements? Whatever that is, that's what's reasonable.

Comment: So if my client want to sends emails with 500MB attachments I should let him do this ??

Comment: Email is not a file transfer protocol.  Repeat that to the guy who wants to do that.

Comment: Its quite hard to explain this to peaople who dont know anything about mail, ftp and simply without any foundations about IT. They simply want to sends bigger emails thats it.

Comment: I did some research and its quite scary(for me and my server performance) .. Google lets send mails with 25 MB attachments that is not that scary  ... but many Polish mail service  providers allows its users to send and receive mails with 100MB  attachments

Comment: If your client want to send files of that size via email then that is up to them. It'll be horribly slow and they may find recipients reject it (we certainly would!) and they will certainly find themselves on the end of all kinds of threats from people who haven't set incoming limits but whose email servers can't handle messages that size, but they won't get a knock on the door from the Internet police or anything! I'd personally doubt the sanity of anyone who used it for emails of that size (or even anything remotely approaching it), but its still their choice.

Comment: I would say it is not hard to explain this to people who don't know anything about mail. "The answer is don't do that. Here's what you do instead." You're in charge of the IT infrastructure, you offer an alternative. I just had this question occur here yesterday (it was for a 5 meg attachment, though.) I asked if it was private, they said no, I said upload it to <website> and email the link. There are other solutions to offer.

Answer (score 1):

Like joeqwerty said in comments - it's impossible to answer as it depends on your organization. A newspaper might need 50MB attachments, Dunder Miffin Paper Co might need 2MB attatchments.

Answer (score 0):

Anything over 10MB is really too big.  The risk is that it will be rejected and bounce or simply never get there. (Also that sent/inboxes become an unmanageable size quicker).

But this isn't a hard and fast rule.  If it is internal or you know the recipient has a large limit there is nothing stopping you from sending bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into trouble going over 20Mb. That might even be too large though depending on your internet bandwidth and number of users. Setting it too high might create a denial of service if people have a habit of sending large attachments out to hundreds of recipients.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, I allow up to 30mb. Externally, 20mb is the limit. I advise users to keep it Nader 15, since many mail systems won't process anything above that. It also gives a little headroom for the size increase that comes with MIME encoding.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea if you follow your client to allow attachment with big size. Default of mail server for attachment is 10 mb.
Why you not use ftp server ? It one solution for file share.

Comment: Ok I know that the ftp is for this but they dont and dont even let me explain that

Comment: My son likes to complain about a problem then when I offer a solution he complains that that's not possible. I eventually realized all he wanted was to do it the original way that he already established isn't feasible, so he would balk at any other solution rather than just doing the actual solution. Eventually I walk away until he realizes he has to bite the bullet and do what he'd prefer not to do. It helps that he's 6, though.